# How to inject user into TokenStorage during KernelTestCase

Tags: symfony, symfony4

One of my event listeners uses `TokenStorageInterface` to access the current user.

During my KernelTestCase (**not** WebTestCase), this event listener is called as well, but now no user is logged in.

How can I inject the user manually in my test?

This does not work:

```
class MyTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /** @var User */
    private $u; // loaded in setup() 

    public function testSimple()
    {
        $tokenStorage = static::$container->get(TokenStorageInterface::class);

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($this->u->getUsername(),null, 'main', ['ROLE_ADMIN']);
        self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token)); // does not work
        $tokenStorage->setToken('', $token); // does not work as well
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad, the solution I had was fine, I just imported the wrong TokenStorageInterface. Here is a full working example:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class MyTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /** @var User */
    private $u; // loaded in setup() 

    public function testSimple()
    {
        $tokenStorage = static::$container->get(TokenStorageInterface::class);
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($this->u, null, 'main', ['ROLE_ADMIN']);
        $tokenStorage->setToken($token); 
    }
}
```